# Pure Imaginary Poles (Why is it problematic?)

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-response

Consider the LCCDE :
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{N}\alpha_{k}\frac{d^{k}f(t)}{dt^{k}}=\sum_{m=0}^{M}\beta_{m}\frac{d^{k}g(t)}{dt^{k}}
\end{equation}
Taking the Fourier transform on both sides, we get :
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{N}\alpha_{k}(2j\pi\lambda)^{k}\widehat{f}(\lambda)=\sum_{m=0}^{M}\beta_{m}(2j\pi\lambda)^{m}\widehat{g}(\lambda)
\tag{1}\end{equation}
Consider the two polynomials :
$$
P(x):=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\alpha_{k}x^{k}\qquad\text{and}\qquad Q(x):=\sum_{m=0}^{M}\beta_{m}x^{m}
$$
Then since $\displaystyle\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ has no poles then $\displaystyle\frac{P(2j\pi\lambda)}{Q(2j\pi\lambda)}$ has no poles for real $\lambda$ and thus $(1)$ becomes :
\begin{equation}
\widehat{g}(\lambda)=\frac{P(2j\pi\lambda)}{Q(2j\pi\lambda)}\widehat{f}(\lambda)
\end{equation}

The impulse response $h=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{H\}$ is computed by decomposing $H$ into partial fractions. The poles $\displaystyle\frac{P}{Q}$ are assumed to lie off the imaginary axis. There are thus two cases to consider :

1. **($\frac{P}{Q}$ has only simple poles)** : In this case, $H$ can be decomposed in the form :
   \begin{equation}
   H(\lambda)=\sum_{m=0}^{M}\frac{\beta_{m}}{2j\pi\lambda-z_{m}}
   \end{equation}
   where $z_{1},z_{2},\cdots,z_{M}$ are the poles. Therefore :
   \begin{equation}
   h(t)=\left(\sum_{m\in \mathcal{M}_{-}}\beta_{m}e^{z_{m}t}\right)u(t)-\left(\sum_{m\in \mathcal{M}_{+}}\beta_{m}e^{z_{m}t}\right)u(-t)
   \end{equation}
   where we define :
   \begin{align*}
   &\mathcal{M}_{-}:=\{m\in\{1,2,\cdots,M\}\;|\;\Re(z_{m})<0\}\\
   &\mathcal{M}_{+}:=\{m\in\{1,2,\cdots,M\}\;|\;\Re(z_{m})>0\}
   \end{align*}
2. **($\frac{P}{Q}$ has multiple poles)** : In this case, let $z_{1},z_{2},\cdots,z_{p}$ the poles and let $\gamma_{1},\gamma_{2},\cdots,\gamma_{p}$ be their multiplicites. Then we can write $H$ as :
   \begin{equation}
   H(\lambda)=\sum_{m=1}^{p}\sum_{\gamma=1}^{\gamma_{m}}\frac{\beta_{m,\gamma}}{(2j\pi\lambda-z_{p})^{\gamma}}
   \end{equation}
   We can see that :
   \begin{equation}
   h(t)=\left(\sum_{m\in \mathcal{M}_{-}}P_{m}e^{z_{m}t}\right)u(t)-\left(\sum_{m\in \mathcal{M}_{+}}P_{m}e^{z_{m}t}\right)u(-t)
   \end{equation}
   where :
   $$
   P_{m}:=\sum_{\gamma=1}^{\gamma_{m}}\beta_{m,\gamma}\frac{t^{\gamma-1}}{(\gamma-1)!}
   $$

> **Remark** : The case where we have **pure imaginary** poles, can not be solved using the two cases above, for a differential equation of the form :
> $$
> g''+\omega^{2} g=f
> $$
> where $\displaystyle\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{1}{x^{2}+\omega^{2}}$ has **two** poles are on the imaginary axis.
> In this case, $h$ is a **sinusoid** and the Fourier transform of $H$ (when $H$ is considered to be a function) is **no longer defined**

I didn't understand why we would be concerned in finding Fourier transform of $H$ as I didn't understand what the author meant by saying **when $H$ is considered to be a function**.

---

**[Reference]** : C. Gasquet, P. Witomski, Fourier Analysis and Applications: Filtering, Numerical Computations, Wavelets. Translated by R. Ryan

Comment: There may be more elsewhere in the book, otherwise it's not clear why the Fourier transform of a sinusoid, or the inverse of its equivalent Laplace transform, are not possible.

Comment: What's remaining of the statement was "This problern will be 
resolved in the context of distributions" which the author wrote there an example of the resonator saying that we *were not 
able to analyze it using the Fourier transform because the poles were on 
the imaginary axis* @aconcernedcitizen

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I was thinking what if he meant that $H$ would be an input in a cascade system and that it's Fourier transform makes a problem?

Comment: There must be a larger context that is not necessarily in that paragraph, or even in that chapter. I can't say anything else based on what I see, and quoting a whole book is not very practical. Maybe some clues are in the past, or yet to come.

Comment: Alright, I shall update my question in a moment to include the details.

Comment: Some things are odd. *Then since P(x)/Q(x) has no poles...* Why not? P(x) and Q(x) are generic polynomials, yet they continue with *h is computed by decomposing into partial fractions...* Decompose what if there are no poles? Then *single poles* and *multiple poles*. Why does that matter when decomposing? The impulse response comes out anyway. And part. decomp. works with purely imag. poles, too. Then *the F.T. of H*. Capital H is the Laplace, so it's an inv. FT, not FT; FT is for h. And of course it's a function, what else? Maybe I'm cranky and not thinking straight. Or it's the translation.